Are these noun phrases from a child's/young adult's book actually noun phrases or are they adjective phrases?
I have an Australian version of Visual Guide to Grammar and Punctuation, and on pg 76 is Noun Phrases. It goes

a noun phrase is a group of words that all belong with the noun and tell us more about it

My initial reaction was, isn't what a adjective does? The book continues...

look at how we can add words to the noun "dog" to make a noun phrase describes what the dog is like (again, describing a noun?)

The book then lists examples

"a small white dog with a little orange collar"
"we saw an old sailing ship with three tall masts"

Since a noun phrase acts like a noun, and a noun can be swapped with a pronoun... for the two examples it would be "it with it" and "we saw an it with it". Those then don't sound correct so it means they are NOT noun phrases? Therefore wouldn't they actually be adjective phrases?

ship is a noun, and an old sailing ship is a noun phrase. But an old sailing ship with three tall masts is also a noun phrase - that contains the adjectival phrase with three tall masts.

Some of the words in the noun phrase are adjectives. (NB It's I'm, not im.)

@FumbleFingers is "old sailing" an adjective phrase as it describes the noun "ship" ?

old and sailing are adjectives, but I don't think it's useful to say old sailing is an "adjectival phrase". It's just two adjectives, which can be "stacked" (applied consecutively) to the same noun. But if you understand the meaning of these texts, I don't see why it matters to you how each sub-component might be categorized. Most native speakers don't know such things, yet they speak and write English perfectly well.

...but note that when a word like sailing (or merchant, battle, war,...) modifies ship, it identifies a specific type of ship. You can call those words "adjectives" if you like, but they're not the same as words like old, large, small, fast,... (which identify an attribute / characteristic of whatever noun they modify). If you have one word from the first group and one word from the second group both used with the same noun, the "type" word (from the first group) must go closest to the noun. So it's always old sailing ship, never sailing old ship.

A noun phrase (NP) is a phrase headed by a noun. This better than "acts like a noun", since "nouns" can act in lots of different ways, including "like an adjective".
So can you identify the headword in the phrase?  In the first, the headword is ship, and in the second the headword is "dog"
The NP "an old sailing ship [with three tall masts]" contains a prepositional phrase in brackets.  It is headed by the preposition "with".  Moreover the PP "with [three tall masts]" contains an NP  "three tall masts".  That NP is headed by the noun "masts".
"We saw it"  is correct grammar. Note that the article "an" is part of the NP.  Of course "We saw it with it" sounds weird because of the repetition of "it", but that clause is also correct grammar.

OP's query is on noun phrase and adjective phrase:

My initial reaction was, isn’t that what an adjective does?

You shouldn’t confuse a noun phrase with an adjective phrase, because an adjective phrase doesn’t contain a head noun.
To distinguish noun phrases from adjective phrases, remember that noun phrases function as subjects or objects, while adjective phrases modify nouns. A reliable way to identify noun phrases is to replace the phrase with an interrogative pronoun (who, what, which, whom, whose)."
Let’s apply this to the example sentences:


"I saw a small white dog with a little orange collar."
"We saw an old sailing ship with three tall masts."


Using interrogative pronouns:.
First sentence: What did I see?
Second sentence: What did we see?
In both cases, the answer is the entire noun phrase:
"a small white dog with a little orange collar".
"an old sailing ship with three tall masts"
Let’s analyze another sentence:
A small white dog with a little orange collar bit an old man walking slowly with a stick.
Using interrogative pronouns:.
Who bit whom?
Here we have two noun phrases:
Subject noun phrase:
"A small white dog with a little orange collar",.
"small white" – adjective phrase describing the dog
Object noun phrase:
"an old man walking slowly with a stick"
"walking slowly with a stick" -
adverbial phrase explaining how the man was walking
In conclusion, by applying the interrogative pronoun replacement test, we can confidently identify noun phrases and distinguish them from adjective phrases."
